# Wrong node type config used after switching databases with db_set_active()

Tags: nodes, caching, importing-exporting

I have a use case where I need to import selected nodes from one D6 site to another and since I have access to both databases, I figured I'd use a custom drush command to select the nodes I wanted from the exporting site and then import them into the receiving site, using db_set_active() to switch between databases depending on what I'm doing.  Here's the code I have so far:

```
function cnsnews_import_mrctv_videos() {
  // First, get defined mappings from the cnsnews_mrctv_import.
  //$mapping_result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {cnsnews_mrctv_import}");
  // Debugging line that only gets one category.
  $mapping_result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {cnsnews_mrctv_import} LIMIT 0, 3");
  while ($mappings = db_fetch_object($mapping_result)) {
    $mapping[$mappings->mrctv_channel] = $mappings->cnsnews_channel;
  }

  // Get variables that store the last nid imported.
  $last_imported_video = variable_get('mrctv_import_last_nid', 0);

  //Next, switch over to mrctv db to get a list of all of the video nodes.
  db_set_active('mrctv');

  foreach($mapping as $mrctv_channel => $cnsnews_channel) {
    // Get all nodes for the channel.
    $sql = "SELECT nid FROM {og_ancestry} WHERE group_nid = %d AND nid > %d";
    $result = db_query($sql, $mrctv_channel, $last_imported_video);
    $imported_nodes = array();
    while ($record = db_fetch_object($result)) {
      $video_node = node_load($record->nid);
      $import_nodes[$mrctv_channel][] = $video_node;
    }
  }
  // Switch back to cnsnews database to begin importing nodes.
  db_set_active('default');
  // Clear out the content_type_info cache entry.
  cache_clear_all('content_type_info:en', 'cache_content'); 

  foreach($import_nodes as $mrctv_channel_id => $video_nodes) {
    // Get the taxonomy term
    $cns_channel_tid = $mapping[$mrctv_channel_id];
    $cns_channel_term = taxonomy_get_term($cns_channel_tid);
    foreach($video_nodes as $video_node) {
      // Create new node object.
      $node = new stdClass();
      $node->title = $video_node->title;
      $node->type = 'video';
      $node->uid = $video_node->uid;
      $node->body = $video_node->body;
      $node->teaser = $video_node->teaser;
      $node->taxonomy[$cns_channel_tid] = $cns_channel_term;
      // Set video field values
      $node->field_video_upload = $video_node->field_video;
      // Modify some settings for CNS.
      unset ($node->field_video_upload[0]['filename']);
      unset ($node->field_video_upload[0]['fid']);
      $node->field_video_upload[0]['data']['dimensions'] = '800x600';
      $node->field_video_upload[0]['data']['player_dimensions'] = '640x480';

      node_save($node);
    }
  }
}
```

I have the default and mrctv databases defined in settings.php.

The issue I'm having is that when I've switched back to the default database and try to import, the field_video_upload field isn't being saved.  I stepped through the code from the content module starting at the node_save() call, and when it is loading the content type fields in _content_type_info() it is getting the info for the video node type in the mrctv database, not the default database.  This is happening even though I am clearing the content_type_info:en entry in the cache_content table.

Is there another cache entry I need to clear out to be able to do this?

Thanks.